# Unable to parse big file in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, server-side

I am working on a project which have approx 300 000 xml files and approx. 800 GB image files in different directories.

I have written a parser in PHP which scans each xml file and reads some tags like title, story, author, image path and writes a new xml file and copies the corresponding image files from different directories to a new directory.

When I run my script to write new xml files and copy the image files then due to the big size, it's unable to complete in 10-12 hours and sometime server is not responding. I have server configuration with i5 processor and 12 GB RAM.

Php script have the following codes for execution time and memory size:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000); 
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

So could someone suggest me that am i doing this in right direction or not? Or do i need to change technologies from php to others?

Comment: Processing this much file is too costly in PHP. You can set maximum execution time to  how much you want by setting this flag in your code or you can directly change it in your php.ini file 
`ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');`
for infinite execution time you can use `ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`.
Another one in the memory limit. mostly the memory limit assigned for your PHP is 256MB. change to how much you need by change the value of `memory_limit = 256M` in php.ini. 
Note:  split the large file into smaller packages and process it.

Comment: Is it necessary to move the image files? Could you change your strategy on that part? For example, the new xml file could simply reference the image files (relatively) where they actually are.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary

Comment: If necessary then you might try and have the php create a shell script, that later does the moving of the files outside of php. In the alternative, you might want to turn this part of the application into a console php script (as opposed to browser), which there is no max execution time limit.